# Elastisearch 2.3.2 limits on resources

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a list of hard limits for Elasticsearch?

I am particularly interested if there is a theoretical limit on the number of indices one can create, and the number of records an index can have.

Answer (score 0):

There are limits to the number of docs per shard of 2 billion, which is a [hard Lucene limit](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LUCENE-5843).

The actual value is `Integer.MAX_VALUE - 128` which is `2147483519` documents per shard.

While asking about the number of documents can be a realistic question, looking at the maximum number of indices is the wrong question. Probably there is a JVM limit, assuming some kind of array or ArrayList that holds these indices (or indices mappings - the cluster state) then the limit would be the size of the array or the size of the ArrayList/HashSet/Map etc.

Way before reaching that theoretical limit your cluster is probably dead or not even able to start. Each shard is using resources, the cluster state would be huge, even with one primary shard only. The correct question would be to ask about performance issues with your cluster and not thinking about the maximum number of indices in a cluster.